# A tool to remove unneeded classes from jar file

Tags: java, software-development, programming

I'm looking for a tool which can remove unneeded classes from jar file (or include only needed ones).

I use maven-based dependency management and build fat jar using `sbt-assembly`. However, the resultant jar is sometimes a bit too fat (e.g., when I have to include a part of `hadoop` package). I am sure that I do not need most of this code (for example, because I use only filesystem and not the whole `mapreduce` package), but by building fat jar I automatically include all the classes.

What I want to do is to either build a jar from only minimal set of classes (I'm open to switching from `sbt` to any other tool that can do this) or removing not needed classes from an existing jar file.

By "not needed" I mean classes which are not imported neither from my main class nor from any of my main class' dependencies.

I am aware that such tools may fail in presence of reflection and other dark magic - this is fine for me, as long as the tool works with the typical scenario (`import`ed classes must be in the package, others have to be removed)

It's great if the tool is open source, but I can live with closed-source version as well, as long as it's not a web tool (corporate IP protection rules)

Comment: Beware of reflection and runtime linkage though, such a tool can only do so much. In principle Java can even load classes depending on user input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this can be achieved with JBOSS `TattleTale` tool. Please see this post for more information:
[Remove unused JARS from project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19099121/remove-unused-jars-from-project)